# DefaultPersistenceUnitName leads to "Entity is not mapped" or "Injection of persistence dependencies failed, no unique bean (found 3)"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a batch project using various `EntityManagerFactory` as it handles 3 different datasources.

In **application-context-spring.xml** :

```
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/j2se-persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myEmf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager"
        ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
</bean>

 <bean id="myEmf2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager"
        ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit2" />
</bean>

 <bean id="myEmf3"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager"
        ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit3" />
</bean>
```

The **j2se-persistence.xml** contains the 3 persistence units.

Now in my Java service, I want to use the third persistence unit :

**MyBatch.java** :

```
@Service("myBatch")
public class MyBatch {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit3")
    private EntityManager em; 

    @Autowired
    private IMyEntity entityDS;

    // ...
}
```

Now the problem is the following : if I specify the default persistence unit name in **application-context-spring.xml** :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" >
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="myEmf"/>
</bean>
```

It works if I set `myEmf3`, but the other batches won't work any longer. And if I set `myEmf` as it was first, I get this error while executing my batch :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyEntity is not mapped

And if I remove this default persistence unit line, I get this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name : Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 3

I don't understand why I get the "is not mapped" error when setting `myEmf` as the default persistence unit as I have clearly annotated my batch's entity manager with `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit3")`. It keeps looking in `myPersistenceUnit` and `myEmf` instead and of course can't find the entity I need to inject. That's why I found while debugging :

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. The solution was to replace :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit3")
private EntityManager em;
```

With :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myEmf3")
private EntityManager em;
```